# How to programmatically find all files referenced from html?

Tags: html, c++, file, download, libcurl

Is it just fine to find all "href" and "src" attributes and check if their values contain something like `"*/*.*"`? The '/' should be probably unique (not "//" because that can be used at start, after the protocol).

I guess the query will be more complicated, but am I thinking about going the right direction? I need to write it in C++ and I will probably use libcurl around, but I guess those facts are not important.

Comment: IMHO, you don't need to validate the values, it could be `a.txt` or `//example.com/scripts/x.js`. Both are valid. But keep in mind if there's a `<base>` tag, it may change the behavior of relative URLs.

Comment: I read a lot of internets and realized that I need to parse html first and then get the referenced files :( sounds too complicated for that simple task.

Comment: In the end I am thinking about using myHTML or Gumbo.

Comment: In the very end, I am using myHTML, because it's faster and more maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I parse the HTML5 and iterate over all the attributes possibly containing URL like this:

```
for (const string& attribute : { "action", "cite", "data", "formaction", "href", "manifest", "poster", "src" })
  iterate_attribute_occurrences_and_possibly_start_downloading(downloader, attribute, with_possible_URL);
iterate_attribute_occurrences_and_possibly_start_downloading(downloader, "srcset", with_possible_comma_separated_URLs);
iterate_attribute_occurrences_and_possibly_start_downloading(downloader, "style", with_CSS_possibly_containing_URLs_in_url_data_type);
```